# How to apply Opacity On A DIV container background only and not change the text and check boxes

Tags: html, css, opacity

Is there a better way to make this work in 2020 on all browsers?

I want to make the background of the div have a reduced opacity and allow the remaining content to stay normal...

```
#menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
  background-color: black; opacity: 0.6;
  width: 180px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: beige;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

sorry I am stupid